# How to access a python dictionary keys as pydantic model fields

Tags: python, pydantic

I am not able to figure out how I can access a dictionary keys using pydantic model properties instead of using get directly on the dictionary.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int

def some_function(data: Person):
    abc=data.name
    print(abc)


person={'name':'tom','age':12}
some_function(person)
```

I get : `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'name'`

Basically, I need to pass a dict to a function which will be received as a Pydantic Model type and then I want to be able to use `. (dot) operator` to access the contents of the passed dict. I have seen something similar implemented but I have no idea why it is not working for me.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Are you trying to make a FastAPI API?
This same some_function will return a <class 'main.Person'> if you make it a FastAPI method. And I am not sure why. https://photos.app.goo.gl/QX76YqKmywHQn6Zm7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your dict to the pydantic class first,

`some_function(Person(**person))`
or
`some_function(Person.parse_obj(person))`